# MSP430 MEMORY ADDRESS IN CCS6

Tags: msp430

I've wrote my very first MSP-EXP430F5529LP LED on/off program.

and I wanted to analyze my program. but I had problem at my first step.

I extracted my LED program from board and I've got unclear data. (3)

that's my first question. what is that file format? I mean I want to know file format for my memory dump file. (3)

my second question is that why CCS 6 doesn't indicate memory address properly?

I know that MSP430 is 16 bit MCU. so every memory address should be 16 bit-width. but my assembly code(2) which is copied from CCS6 Disassembly View show me address just like 01XXXX format.

relative data dereference and execution flow branches work well. but why CSS6 make me confused? I mean I want to know that why CCS6 display memory addresse 24 bit-width??

anyone who know where is TI document which explain what I want to know, please let me know. please just don't mention MSP430xxxx User's Guide.

sorry for my english :(

1.c code

```
#include <msp430f5529.h>

volatile unsigned int i;

void main(void) {
    WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD;
    P1DIR |= 0x01;
    while(1){
        P1OUT ^= 0x01;
        for(i = 20000;i > 0; i--);
    }
}
```

2.assembly code

```
0100c2:   40B2 5A80 015C      MOV.W   #0x5a80,&Watchdog_Timer_WDTCTL
0100c8:   D3D2 0204           BIS.B   #1,&Port_A_PADIR
0100cc:   E3D2 0202           XOR.B   #1,&Port_A_PAOUT
0100d0:   40B2 4E20 2400      MOV.W   #0x4e20,&i
0100d6:   3C02                JMP     (0x00dc)
0100d8:   8392 2400           DEC.W   &i
0100dc:   9382 2400           TST.W   &i
0100e0:   27F5                JEQ     (0x00cc)
0100e2:   3FFA                JMP     (0x00d8)
0100e4:   4303                NOP     
0100e6:   D032 0010           BIS.W   #0x0010,SR
0100ea:   3FFD                JMP     (0x00e6)
0100ec:   431C                MOV.W   #1,R12
0100ee:   0110                RETA    
0100f0:   4303                NOP     
0100f2:   3FFF                JMP     (0x00f2)
```

3.memory dump (MAIN)

```
:1044000031400044b113ec000c930224b1130000be
:104410000c43b113c200b113f00000000200000011
:10442000840001001a44000000240000ffffffff89
:10443000ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff8c
:10444000ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff7c
...
...
```

Answer (score 1):

If one reads the User Guide (which is why they exist) then one is informed that the Program Counter is 20-bit. So, now you know why you see an address in the 20-bit range.

Link to the MSP430 User Guide: http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau208n/slau208n.pdf

> The 20-bit PC (PC/R0) points to the next instruction to be executed.
>   Each instruction uses an even number of bytes (2, 4, 6, or 8 bytes),
>   and the PC is incremented accordingly. Instruction accesses are
>   performed on word boundaries, and the PC is aligned to even addresses.
>   Figure 6-3 shows the PC.

The above is an excerpt from the User Guide. I cannot emphasis this enough - but you really need to read the User Guide. Not doing so and attempting to program microcontrollers is perlious to your mental health.

The memory dump seems to be in the Intel hex file format https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HEX

Comment: thanks a lot!
thanks to you I've figured out how much important to read user's guide :)